# How Do I Retrieve A Selected Image Using onActivityResult?

Tags: android

I have a button that I want to use to go into the user's image library and they can select an image. I then want to display it in the imageView on the page.

```
 public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    public void getPhoto(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setBackground(requestCode);
    }
}
```

I have been able to successfully select the image, and now I want to use the onActivityResult to set my imageView to the new image.

I thought I would do this by using either the requestCode, resultCode, or data, but I can't quite seem to work out how. Any guidance would be excellent.

Comment: imageView.setImageURI(data.getData());

Comment: Thank you! If I can ask, how do you learn all of this? When you look at the documentation, it feels like theres links to links that you have to click to understand stuff and I just don't know how you even approach such an expansive system.

Comment: 1. Read every day stackoverflow pages tagged android.

Comment: 2. If you type imageView. then just after typing the dot Android Studio will show all kind of functions you can use. Have a look at them.

Comment: 3. Google for examples.

Comment: 4. There are many sites for programmers with a lot of examples for standard tasks.

Comment: Thanks again Amigo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
   if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
     Uri file = data.getData(); // you can find path also from here
      ImageView.setImageURI(file)
     }
```

}